# Unable insert in mysql table when I call another php

Tags: php, mysqli

When I press register button in  crudindex.php It will insert data in to cruduser(table)
once done Call crudadd.php and insert data into crud(table) with max(id) from cruduser table as id.

The issue is :Once I press REGISTER button Cruduser(table) is getting inserted properly.
But  In crud(table) it inserts only the id and other fields are blank.
I have a doubt the post is not picking the values or insert command some issues.

But when I give static values ex : firstname as 'Tim', lastname as 'cook' etc its inserting in the table crud.

Also when I run crudadd.php separately  it inserts properly.

Structure :

```
cruduser(
  id(int),
  username(varchar),
  password(varchar)
)

crud(
  id(int),
  firstname(varchar),
  lastname(varchar),
  email(varchar),
  gender(varchar),
  age(varchar)
)
```

used : tables : cruduser and crud
php : crudindex.php and crudadd.php

Core issue : data is not properly inserted in to crud table

Crudindex.php

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "kkits996_ganesh", "mysql123#", "kkits996_testmysql")  or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));
if (isset($_POST) && (!empty($_POST))){
 $uname=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["uname"]);
 $pwd=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["pwd"]);
 $cpwd=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["cpwd"]);
if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
        # Register-button was clicked
$createsql1="INSERT INTO cruduser(id,username,password) VALUES
                             ('','$uname','$pwd')";

if (mysqli_query($con,$createsql1)) {
echo "Insert Successful in Table cruduser";
mysqli_close($con);
include ("crudadd.php");
}
else
{
die(mysqli_error($con));
}
}
mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
<!--DocType HTML -->
<! bootstrap link is downloaded from bootstrapcdn.com for css and js -->
<! col-mod-6 col-mod-offset are bootstrap related-->
<HTML>
<head>
<title>"Add records in CRUD Table"</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container"> 
<div class="row">
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal col-mod-6 col-mod-offset-3">
<h2>Create The table CRUD</h2>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="input" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Firstname</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" name="uname" class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Username"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="input" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Lastname</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" name="pwd" class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Password"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="input" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" name="cpwd" class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Confirm Password"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">

                <div class="col-mod-6 col-mod-offset-3">
                   <button id="submit1" name="register" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Register</button>
                  <button id="submit2" name="login" class="btn btn-secondary pull-right">Login</button>
                </div>
            </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Crudadd.php

```
<?php
//session_start();
//$maxiid = $_SESSION['id'];
//echo $maxiid;

$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "kkits996_ganesh", "mysql123#", "kkits996_testmysql")  or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM cruduser WHERE id=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM cruduser)");
$row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$c1 = $row1['id'];
mysqli_close($con);

$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "kkits996_ganesh", "mysql123#", "kkits996_testmysql")  or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));
if (isset($_POST) && (!empty($_POST))){
 $fname=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["fname"]);
 $lname=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["lname"]);
 $email=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["email"]);
 $gender=$_POST["gender"];
 $age=$_POST["age"];

print "I am here";
echo $finame;
echo $liname;
print email;
//Notes : In Insert if numeric do not use quotes. if string use quotes.for auto use ''
$createsql="INSERT INTO crud(id,firstname,lastname,email,gender,age) VALUES
                         ($c1,'$fname','$lname','$email','$gender','$age')";

if (mysqli_query($con,$createsql)) {
echo "Connection Successful";
}
else
{
echo "Connection Issue";
die(mysqli_error($con));
}
mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
<!--DocType HTML -->
<! bootstrap link is downloaded from bootstrapcdn.com for css and js -->
<! col-mod-6 col-mod-offset are bootstrap related-->
<HTML>
<head>
<title>"Add records in CRUD Table"</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container"> 
<div class="row">
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal col-mod-6 col-mod-offset-3">
<h2>Create The table CRUD</h2>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="input" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Firstname</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" name="finame" class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="First name"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="input" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Lastname</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" name="liname" class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Last name"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="input" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" name="eimail" class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Email"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="input" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Gender</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<label>
<input type="radio" name="giender" id="optionsRadios1" value="male" checked> Male
</label>
<label>
<input type="radio" name="giender" id="optionsRadios1" value="female" > Female
</label>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="input" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Age</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<select name="aige" class="form-control">
<option>Select your age</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
<option value="24">24</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="26">26</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn=primary col-md-2 col-md-offset-10" value="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Some sensible indention might be in order.

Comment: strange your labels and inputs are not equivalent.. !!!

Comment: yes I got your point. for testing have changed with some names,Even you keep the names correctly. the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While clicking on 'Register' you are sending `uname`, `pwd` and `cpwd` ina POST request which are properly used to be inserted into `cruduser`. After that you are including the crudadd.php (`include ("crudadd.php");`). But remember you are still at the same request. So the only data available is `uname`, `pwd` and `cpwd`. This is why your rows are semi-empty.

Comment: How to solve this.How to get the post data in crudadd.php and insert into table crud.

Comment: Adjust your first form to have all necessary fields or solve the registration in two steps (e.g. not include cruddadd.php but redirect to it)

Comment: Nice redirect worked. Also one small basic doubt. In the crudadd.php . I have opened the connection and closed twise i.e 1 for select and second time for insert statement. Is it required twise to open and close the connection OR only one time i will open the connection and run the select and insert and finally close the connection.

Comment: It's not needed (nor recommended) to open a connection for every query. In fact you could also remove the `mysqli_close` call as it will be closed on script end automatically (but this is not recommended).

Answer (score 0):

if Id is AUTO INCREMENT.
you must use

```
$createsql1="INSERT INTO cruduser(id,username,password) VALUES
                             (NULL,'$uname','$pwd')";
```

not ((you can not set string for id value. Your id is of int type ))

```
$createsql1="INSERT INTO cruduser(id,username,password) VALUES
                             ('','$uname','$pwd')";
```